# How to to manage & develop big TYPO3 projects?  

Tags: php, project-management, typo3

I am developing TYPO3 projects since 2006 now, and projects are getting bigger and more complex. Setting up a simple CMS site with a contact form and news listing is all routine.

Right now, we finished a bigger project: A platform for an international company with countless extensions:
Login & registration, news, listing database records, dynamic contact forms, surveys & statistics, intranet functions: document upload & download, several backend "tweaks" per TCA modifications, etc. .

The project managers got upset at us developers, because sometimes, after we finished on function X and later committed function Y to the dev server, function X was broken. This was related to typoscript settings, extension interdependencies, versioning errors or sometimes simple programming mistakes and typos.
I know how to take care of the latter, but in general:

From your experience:

> **How can we develop an error-proof system in TYPO3, where everything works in hand and extensions don't get in their way?** In other words:
>   How can we secure and isolate functionalities (extensions) - and avoid those interdepency issues?

We are working in a DEV team with two developers, and we already use:

- Subversion Repository
- Local DEV server for development & testing
- External typoscript configuration files, split into single files for each extension

**Edit for Bountyhunters:**

What I am looking for is a best-practice-summary that might include these topics:

- General workflow habits
- General coding habits
- Reliability of our subversion commits (or Git)
- Unit testing (PHPUnit, Selenium?)
- Deployment (I haven't yet figured out how automated deployment can
  help us)
- Typoscript best practices

Comment: Use one of the many automatic deployment systems. Have a look into the english and dev mailing list archives. Similar threads appear in frequently.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, I couldn't find anything related to "automatic deployment" in the english mailing list, but will look further. Can you recommend a system for PHP/TYPO3? We already consider using PHPUnit and Selenium for testing, I suppose that this might be an important improvement, too.

Comment: Have a look here: https://usetypo3.com/good-practices-in-projects.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [project management is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343841) You can ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Problems we could find in large TYPO3 projects are not to much different from any development project.

General practices :

- configure [continuous integration platform](http://jenkins-ci.org/) with [continuous deployment tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano_(software));
- Test Driven Development with automated testing;
- robust architecture (dB, URL routing, ...);
- [performance tests](http://jmeter.apache.org/) during development;
- use versionning with formatted comments;
- use powerful IDE as PHPStorm, Eclipse, Netbeans;

Common TYPO3 practices :

- use [official API](http://typo3.org/documentation/api/);
- follow [TYPO3 API code guideline](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_cgl/current/view/);
- use [TYPO3 hooks](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/current/view/3/4/) where You can if You need to modify the logic of Core or 3rd party extensions;
- use [TypoScript constants](http://wiki.typo3.org/TypoScript_Constants) to separate data from logic in Your configuration;

Additional references :

- [TYPO3 Best Practice Workshop](http://jweiland.net/uploads/media/TYPO3-Best-Practice-Workshop.pdf)
- [TYPO3 Best Practices (de)](http://www.jochen-froehlich.de/typo3-best-practice.html)
- [TDD & Best Practices mit TYPO3 (de)](http://www.slideshare.net/oliverklee/tdd-best-practices-mit-typo3)

Extensions could help to manage complex TYPO3 installation :

- [caretaker](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-caretaker)
- [additional reports](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/show/extension-additional_reports/)

Use modern project management methodologies & tools

- Scrum, Kanban, lean developement principles
- Bugtrackers as Redmine, Trac

Books :

- [php|architect's Guide to Enterprise PHP Development](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-enterprise-php-development/)

Comment: That looks like an extensive collection, thanks. I actually rarely use constants, rather setup - one detail learned.  Have you personally used the extension phpunit, which is mentioned in Oliver Klees slides?

Comment: Personally, I'm using it every time, when I've some complex projects / extension to develop.

Comment: UPDATE : Added a list of recommended extensions for large TYPO3 installation management

Comment: Your Capistrano's link is pointing to John of Capistrano wikipedia page. Please update to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano_(software)

Answer (score 4):

I absolutely recommmend start using [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/) for unit testing, but remember unit testing is really about how you create the code in the first place, not usually something you add later. But of course, better late than never.

You should consider setting up a build server like jenkins/hudson or [atlassian bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview). The latter is quite nice and integrates with zend studio which in my opinion is the better choice when developing in PHP. In general the [atlassian](http://atlassian.com) products are widely used for software projects. (Jira + confluence + greenhopper in particular)

Comment: Tanks for your input. As we develop in Netbeans - is Bamboo still a good choice as there doesn't yet exist a Bamboo Netbeans plugin? Would it be efficient to be used without Netbeans integration? Also, is a setup of this kind recommended for TYPO3 environments?

Comment: For sure. Bamboo is a standalone product and the integration allows you to get comments and pointers to where the build failed directly into the code. You can ofcourse see all this on the webpage and I even think they have a mobile phone app for it. Don't take my word for it though, check out their videos.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend setting up phpunit on jenkins - see http://jenkins-php.org/ as a template, although I've read good feedback about Teamcity. Then, depending on the code you write you setup unit tests (for raw php code, maybe a bit with of mocks), integration tests (API and module connectivity) and system tests (selenium).

Once you have it running after each build you can be sure that at least covered functionality is working. The problem however is that you will spend more time on writing tests and their support as well as thinking about testable code. Also keep in mind that you cannot cover everything - thats not the point. You must have critical paths covered.